# Does an iterator iterate through boost::unordered_set or boost::unordered_map in the same order as long as the set's unchanged?

Tags: c++, boost-unordered

Does an iterator iterate through `boost::unordered_set` or `boost::unordered_map` in the same order as long as the set or the map is unchanged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some implementations of a hash map will reorder the items that hash to the same bin, putting the most recently accessed item at the front of a list, as an optimization. This would change the order. I'm not aware that `boost::unordered_map` does this, but in the future you might end up substituting `std::unordered_map` and it will all depend on your compiler's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be deterministic but as long as they are so-called *unordered*, you should not rely on this to iterate over your elements.